# Propagating touch events

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, android-pageradapter, android-touch-event

I have trouble implementing something like Instagram preview image feature (on long press show dialog with enlarged image). So i have `Fragment` with `ViewPager` as its child. `Adapter` responsible for feeding the data to the`ViewPager` has one imageView with `onTouchListener`. That listener has `gestureDetector` for detecting `onDoubleTap` and `onLongPress`. Now the thing is that i want `onLongPress` to inflate the `Dialog` in the parent `Fragment`, and on release i want to dismiss the `Dialog`. But for some reason, `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` or `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` never gets called in the pagerAdapter, i guess that Dialog is intercepting the actions, and it is so frustrating, i cant implement this for days... Simply cant figure it how does `TouchEvent` system works.. Here is the code:

**PagerAdapter:**

```
private class MyOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {



    private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(mContext, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)
            listener.performSomeAction();
            return super.onDoubleTap(e);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            int action = e.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    listener.setZoomLayout(imageUri);
                    break;
                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
                    listener.hideZoomLayout();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    listener.hideZoomLayout();
                    break;
            }
            super.onLongPress(e);
        }

    });

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.ivSelectedImg1:
                gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            case R.id.ivSelectedImg2:
                gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            case R.id.ivSelectedImg3:
                gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            case R.id.ivSelectedImg4:
                gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
                default: return false;
        }

    }
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
@Override
public void setZoomLayout(String imageUri) {
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_image_zoom, null);

    ImageView zoomImage = view.findViewById(R.id.ivImageZoom);

    zoomImage.setClickable(false);
    zoomImage.setFocusable(false);


    GlideApp.with(getActivity())
            .load(imageUri)
            .into(zoomImage);

    dialogBuilder = new Dialog(getActivity(), -1);
    dialogBuilder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialogBuilder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialogBuilder.setContentView(view);
    dialogBuilder.show();
```

Don`t get how to prevent inflating Dialog to take over the MotionEvent. I mean, i am not even sure that event is getting caught in the dialog, looks like its gone. Thanks a lot in advance!